# How to setup Jboos Drools in Eclipse

Tags: drools

I am trying to do the eclipse set up for writing the Business Rules  and exporting them to repository

Can any one explain how to setup jboos Drools/BRMS in eclipse for Writing Business Rules and exporting them to the Guvnor repository.

Comment: Add more related tags to reach more people.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the drools.org official documentation? 
You need to install the drools plugin via the Eclipse Market place and then have a running instance of guvnor (I believe that with the 5.5 version it will work).